# oracle forms - web config file

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

We are running an application over oracle forms 11 g . 
we are planning to set up 2 web url links in the same web server for different languages. We are looking forward to set up an variable at the web config file or environment config file. And during runtime check the values of this variable and display forms data to the used in the forms. Can you please help me on setting up this variable and how to get this value during runtime? thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup 2 different configurations in the formsweb.cfg.  You would have a default.env ( or whatever name you wanted to give ) for each one.  When you launch from the web url link, you would define your configuration name ( config=LANG1, config=LANG2 ).  Within forms, you can then use get_application_property( CONFIG ) to return to you which language you were in.